# Can't change heap size AMD64

Tags: assembly, heap-memory, brk

I'm trying to increase the heap size by 100 by changing the brk and I don't know why my code doesn't work. 
Here is the part of the code that tries do it:

```
movq $0, %rdi
movq $12, %rax
syscall
movq %rax, InicialHeap

movq InicialHeap, %rsi
mov $str, %rdi
call printf

movq $100, %rdi
movq $12, %rax
syscall

movq %rax, %rsi
mov $str, %rdi
call printf

movq InicialHeap, %rdi
movq $12, %rax
syscall

movq InicialHeap, %rsi
mov $str, %rdi
call printf

movq $60, %rax
syscall
```

The program should print something like:

x (print InicialHeap)

x + 100 (print InicialHeap + 100)

x (print InicialHeap)

 But it only prints 3 times the same result "x". 
 What do I have to do to increase my heap size?

Comment: Why would it add 100 in the second call, but not add the value stored in `InicialHeap` in the third call?

Comment: Can you rerun your program with strace and post results? For example, `strace ./a.out`. Strace will print all syscalls, decode their parameters and show and decode return values. What is your OS? In linux brk is a bit strange: http://linux.die.net/man/2/brk.

Comment: Although not an answer to this question, some example 32-bit code (not 64-bit) using NASM (Not GNU assembler) can be found in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33903235/3857942 . The code does use the `brk` 32-bit syscall but the idea in that code should be adaptable to use the 64-bit syscalls in your assembler with minimal effort.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Answer (score 0):

As the NOTES section of [the man page for `int brk(void *addr);` describes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html), the system call (`__NR_brk` = `12`) actually implements `brk()`, not `sbrk`, but returns the current break rather than an integer.

As @osgx comments, try running your program under strace to see what return values you're getting.  e.g. from `strace /bin/true`, you can see that it's normal for the dynamic linker to start off by using `brk(0)` to find out the current break:

```
brk(0)                                  = 0x24c6000
```

From there, you should save the return value, and make your next call to `brk()` with an offset from that.

---

Your current code clearly can't work:

```
movq $100, %rdi
movq $12, %rax
syscall             ;;  brk((void*)100)
```